# Want my bot to delete message when the user reacts with an emoji

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I've created a bookmark bot that sends a DM to the user who reacts to a message with the bookmark emoji. The bot sends the message URL in a DM to the user, and reacts with an X emoji. The idea is that when the user reacts with the X emoji in the DM channel also, the message deletes.

However, it's not quite working right. And the message deletes itself when navigating to the DM channel.

Here's my code;

```
import discord
import os
from datetime import datetime

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
embed = discord.Embed()
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  message_id = payload.message_id
  channel_id = payload.channel_id
  channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)

  if isinstance(channel,discord.channel.DMChannel) == False:

    emoji = payload.emoji

    user = payload.member
    message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
  
    if emoji.name == "":
      print(user.id)
      print(message.content)
      print("Channel ID = " + str(channel_id))
      #print(emoji.name)
  

      send = await user.send("**Bookmark Created:** " + str(datetime.now())[:-7] + "\n" + message.jump_url)
      await send.add_reaction("❌")

  elif isinstance(channel,discord.channel.DMChannel) == True:
    dm_message_id = payload.message_id
    dm_channel_id = payload.channel_id
    #guild_id = payload.guild_id
    #guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    dm_channel = client.get_channel(dm_channel_id)
    dm_emoji = payload.emoji
    dm_user = payload.member

    dm_message = await dm_channel.fetch_message(dm_message_id)
    if dm_emoji.name == "❌":
      await dm_message.delete()

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure that the bot isn't responding to it's own reactions. You can add this check around anything you don't want the bot to respond to.

```py
if payload.member == client.user:
```

Or if you also want to ignore other bots.

```py
if not(payload.member.bot):
```

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your comment, I see what the issue is. When the user reacts to the message, the message which the user reacted to is the one that gets deleted, **NOT** the message that is "bookmarked". From my understanding of the code, what you aim to do is delete the message that was linked in the text body of the message (i.e. the url in the body of the message, which you can extract by doing [message.contents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.content)).

To convert a message url to the actual mean you can use the [MessageConverter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MessageConverter) class that is availale with discord.py. You are going to need to use the convert method. Which looks up in the following order (from the docs):

The lookup strategy is as follows (in order):

1. Lookup by “{channel ID}-{message ID}” (retrieved by shift-clicking on “Copy ID”)
2. Lookup by message ID (the message must be in the context channel)
3. Lookup by message URL

Comment: Sorry, but I'm struggling to see how that resolves my problem. I think my issue is regarding syntax. Care to elaborate on your solution?

Comment: @RaheelShaikh updated my answer, please take a look. From my understanding of the code, you are deleting the message that the user reacts to, not the message that is linked in the body of the message.